# My App is in review or pending publication in google play store

Tags: google-play-console, publishing

Its my first experience to upload my app to google play store and I personally developed so I dont think so that I used any illegal thing it it but Its in review for last 2 days.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The process can take even more than that, what you can do is make sure that:
-you ask the proper permissions, more permissions you need, more time for the store to give you an answer. If you ask for dangerous permissions, you must explain clearly why you want them, else your app will be rejected.

- you describe your app well and detailed. This will improve your chances for fast approval
- have all the fields filled in properly, like agreement, pictures and videos of different sizes
- don't forget about category and ads. If you have ads and chose that the app is available to kids, you can expect a much more detailed check of your app, which takes longer
- check all the warning messages you have on the dashboard. Most of them are very useful info.
  My advice is to take time to sort all these as best as you can and later you will enjoy fast approvals and easy updating.